# How do I query and empty array in SQL (for aws quicksight)

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

When running the following query I get the following, but within the sensitive data column there is I believe some empty arrays for example the cell will have "[]".

```
SELECT
DISTINCT SUBSTRING(createdat, 1, 10) datee,
classificationdetails.jobid,
classificationdetails.result.sensitivedata
FROM "demo"."crawler_tbl_with_s3_sqseu_west_2";
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wzy71.png)

I want to be able to select the empty arrays specifically. So I would like to add a where condition that enables me to select specifically the cells with "[]".

I have tried with the query below, the results of the error of the query will be below the query.

```
SELECT 
distinct classificationdetails.result.sensitivedata as sens,
createdat
FROM "demo"."crawler_tbl_with_s3_sqseu_west_2"
WHERE classificationdetails.result.sensitivedata = '[]' ;
```

Here is what I am doing atm but get the error

SYNTAX_ERROR: line 5:50: '=' cannot be applied to array(row("category" varchar,"totalcount" varchar,"detections" array(row("type" varchar,"count" varchar,"occurrences" row("lineranges" array(varchar),"pages" array(varchar),"records" array(varchar),"cells" array(row("row" varchar,"column" varchar,"columnname" varchar))))))), varchar(2)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your errors (and code if any) as **text** rather than as screenshot(s). On stack overflow images should not be used for text, see [*Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) and [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The sensitive data field is an array object, so you can't directly compare it with the '[]' string. To do that you have to transform it to string with the functions array_to_string(), array_join(), etc.

```
SELECT 
distinct classificationdetails.result.sensitivedata as sens,
createdat
FROM "demo"."crawler_tbl_with_s3_sqseu_west_2"
WHERE array_to_string(classificationdetails.result.sensitivedata,'') = '' ;
```